# How to use my php variable UserNameID to delete the user's row in the database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want the user to be able to remove their account from the database, this will be done by the click of a button in my php forum, see code below.

```
  <div  class="btn-group">
    <button style="width:200px" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Change details</button>
    <button style="width:200px" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add details</button>
    <button onclick="myFunction()" style="width:200px" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Delete details</button>
    </div>
```

I already have the database connection setup

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'Oliver'); 
mysql_select_db('users');    
$query = "SELECT * FROM username WHERE username='$login_session'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);       
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){      
$name = $row['name'];
$username = $row['username'];
$sex = $row['sex'];
$phone = $row['phone'];
$email = $row['email'];
$dob = $row['dob'];
$image = $row['imagelink'];
$hobby = $row['hobby'];
$bio = $row['Bio'];
$Level = $row['Level'];
$UserNameID = $row['UserNameID'];
}    
mysql_close(); 
?>
```

The database row will be identified by the php variable UserNameID which is from the database

```
$UserNameID = $row['UserNameID'];
```

If you need any more info please just drop me a response, i'm quite new to coding so cooperation will be needed :D Thanks ever so much

**Update** 
Instead of disliking please tell me what i'm doing wrong, that would be hugely appreciated

**Update**

This is the session code

```
<?php
// Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "Oliver");
// Selecting Database
$db = mysql_select_db("users", $connection);
session_start();// Starting Session
// Storing Session
$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];
// SQL Query To Fetch Complete Information Of User
$ses_sql=mysql_query("select username from username where username='$user_check'", $connection);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);
$login_session =$row['username'];
if(!isset($login_session)){
mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection
header('Location: home.php'); // Redirecting To Home Page
}
?>
```

This just logs the user in if details are match in the database and starts a session to unlock other pages

Comment: where is your `onclick="myFunction()"` code?

Comment: what issue are you facing???

what is value of `$login_session` ??? ID of user??? then just delete the profile .... simple is that ...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i'm struggling to figure out how i set up a button press to delete the row with the UserNameID in that's located in the database

Comment: I don't have it set up set up yet @shehary i don't know what to put inside of it

Comment: Why iterate through the user's table? You probably should also ensure the user that is deleting is the user that is logged in. Request could be constructed to remove other user accounts. Also depending on how you process that request may open you to SQL injection. Be sure to use prepared statements.

Comment: Thank you im working on preventing SQL injection at the moment too, im learning as i construct the site, it will never be open best my personal network anyway, it will also be hosted here too

Answer (score 0):

I think this will move you bit closer to your goal.

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button style="width:200px" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Change details</button>
    <button style="width:200px" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add details</button
    <form action="" method="post">
        <button type="submit" style="width:200px" class="btn btn-primary">Delete details</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="UserName id="UserName" value="<?php echo $login_session;?>" />
    </form>
</div>

<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'Oliver'); 
mysql_select_db('users');    
$query = "SELECT * FROM username WHERE username='$login_session'";
$result = mysql_query($query); 
//By the way you don't need loop here      
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){      
        $name = $row['name'];
        $username = $row['username'];
        $sex = $row['sex'];
        $phone = $row['phone'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        $dob = $row['dob'];
        $image = $row['imagelink'];
        $hobby = $row['hobby'];
        $bio = $row['Bio'];
        $Level = $row['Level'];
        $UserNameID = $row['UserNameID'];
    }
    //Here you delete record from database
        if(isset($_POST['UserName'])){
        $user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['UserName']);
        //Strongly suggest that use UserId to delete record not username
        $sql = "DELETE FROM username WHERE username='$user' LIMIT 1";
    }       
mysql_close(); 
?>
```

Edited According to OP request

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'Oliver'); 
mysql_select_db('users');
if(isset($_POST['UserName'])){ 
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['UserName']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM username WHERE username='$user'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$total = mysql_num_rows($result);   
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
// You dont need to fetch all records just `$UserNameID` enough
$name = $row['name'];
$username = $row['username'];
$sex = $row['sex'];
$phone = $row['phone'];
$email = $row['email'];
$dob = $row['dob'];
$image = $row['imagelink'];
$hobby = $row['hobby'];
$bio = $row['Bio'];
$Level = $row['Level'];
$UserNameID = $row['UserNameID'];

//Here you delete record from database
    if($total>0){
        $sql = "DELETE FROM username WHERE UserNameID='$UserNameID' LIMIT 1";
    }
}
mysql_close(); 
?>
```

Comment: Okay not im just 100% confused :D I'm super new to coding, I understand the problem is with the bootstrap modal and you want me to create a new php document, what would you like me to put in it and what should i save it as?

Comment: give me a moment, wiil create another pastebin

Comment: Still not working, want to add me on facebook, its easier to chat, its nearly working

Comment: one last try add `ob_start(); ` in your delete.php file after <?php and change `$_POST` to `$_REQUEST` 3 places in total in your delete.php file also can you see user id in bootstrap modal in input? also i just see a typo mistake in bootstrap modal `name="Userid"` replace with `name="UserId"`

Comment: made the changes and still not working :/ what do you mean  can you see user id in bootstrap modal in input and yes i can see the UserNameID value next to the delete details button

Comment: means when modal opens, do you see an input with value in it? which is right next to delete button

Comment: did you change this `<input type="text" name="Userid" id="UserId" value="<?php echo $UserNameID;?>" />` to this `<input type="text" name="UserId" id="UserId" value="<?php echo $UserNameID;?>" />`

Comment: actually its not your fault, i m just too tired, another typo mistake, change this `<input type="hidden" name="action value="Delete" />` to this `<input type="hidden" name="action" value="Delete" />` in form in modal

Comment: Made those changes and it's still not working :D This is making me tired too :P just so confused why we carn't get it to work :D

Comment: then my friend, today is not working day, the code i gave you its 100% working, im using same code and i just made changes in it according to your requirement and it should be working, ok lets give it one more shot change this `<button type="submit" style="width:200px" class="btn btn-primary">Delete details</button>` to this `<input type="submit" style="width:200px" class="btn btn-primary" value="Delete details">`

Comment: $UserId = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['UserId']); should this be $UserId = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['UserNameID']); ?

Comment: no its should be `$UserId = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['UserId']);` becoz from the form you are posting has the input `<input type="text" name="UserId" id="UserId" value="<?php echo $UserNameID;?>" />` so it is getting value from input and input `name="UserId` must be same as `$_REQUEST['UserId']`

Comment: change this in your delete.php file `$query = "SELECT UserNameID FROM username WHERE username='$userid'";` to this `$query = "SELECT UserNameID FROM username WHERE UserNameID='$userid'";`

Comment: That does not seem to work either, want a clone of my site to take a look at it?

Comment: sure, i have an hour left to hit the bed so let me have final look at it

Comment: so far i found and all i did is typo mistakes, change this `$query = "SELECT UserNameID FROM username WHERE UserNameID='$userid'";` to this `$query = "SELECT UserNameID FROM username WHERE UserNameID='$UserId'";` in your delete.php file , above i m fetching $UserId and inside query im trying to fetch the data with $userid, so its not fetching anything

Comment: Okay I have changed that :P